# Conv2 function values goes above 255 when convolving an image and a window?

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I have a window of size 5*5.An image of size 360*300.When i convolve the two using the function.I am working on matlab.

```
conv2(image,window,'same');
```

the values of the pixel goes above 255.I used the code below to restrict the value below 255.

```
 ( conv2(image,window,'same')/sum(sum(window));
```

I have 3 questions which are listed below.

1. Is it the right way to proceed??
2. Does the function take care of this constraint also?
3. Any alternate method?

Comment: Or you could just ensure that the sum of window equals one. also btw `sum(sum(window))` can be written as `sum(window(:))`

Comment: @Dan if my sum of windows equals to one how can i restrict the values less than 255?

Comment: if the sum of all elements in `window` is less than `1`, then the result of the convolution can never go larger than the maximum value of the image which I'm assuming is `255`. So that does the restriction for you. It's basically the same thing as what you're doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To specify what is said in the comments:
The overall sum of your window

```
ws = sum(window(:))
```

is like an amplification. If `ws>1`, then your image tends to get brighter. If `0 < ws < 1` your image will get darker. If `ws = 0`, then you will receive an image, that will average at about zero. This is often the case in edge detection scenarios. For example, the [Sobel Operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sobel_operator) has a sum of zero.

Often, the convolution is executed with an amplification equal to 1, to separate the amplification from the convolution. As convolution is a linear operator, it does not matter whether you divide the window by `ws` or the resulting image.

To answer questions 1 and 3 in particular: The usual way is to normalize the window. That is:

```
window = window ./ sum(window(:)); % Normalize convolution kernel
conv2(image,window,'same');
```